# PHP's regular expression engine to remove all html tags, replace with a placeholder, and then add them back in

Tags: php, regex

I'm working with content API's that require HTML be stripped and only text remain, but I want to reinsert the html tags so as to restore the html to the content body after it has been altered by the remote API.

Does anyone know an elegant solution to achieve this offhand?

Hudson

Comment: If the content has to be stripped down... how are you going to be able to use that formatting information later?

Comment: You want to re-insert tags into an modified text, so even if you know the exact positions of the tags in the original string you still don't know if it would make sense to add the tags at those locations. For all I know the text could have been translated...

Comment: That's the case. Let's imagine translation is exactly what I was trying to do (Although most translation APIs account for HTML but the principle is the same). I would need to remove HTML, perform actions on content, and then restore html. I imagined this could be done with preg_match_all, arrays and loops.

Comment: The only decent solution is to use an API that does allow html in the input and that makes sure that tags and tag positions remain correct when the text is altered.

Comment: Essentially they would have to have the same technology working on their side. It would be a nice piece of code to have.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to store a stripped copy of the data (perhaps via strip_tags as suggested), and also to store an original copy.

Any placeholder you leave in will likely corrupt your non-html code, making it easier to maintain two copies.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is your friend here. Great example here:http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html.

Use [preg_replace](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to strip out the html tags and replace with your own placeholder (like ||||). Save the matches for when your code is returned and walk through the string looking for the next |||| using [str_replace](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and shift the top array element off using [array_shift](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

Comment: How would you save the striped html tags?